# Unit Test library is called from wrapper library

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, closures

I am building a wrapper around a javascript library in [pinojs](https://github.com/pinojs/pino).
I'm wondering how I can write a unit test to verify the `info` function within `pino` was actually called.

Here's a code snippet

```
const { logger } = require(`../../../lib/index`);

describe(`when logger is configured with pino-pretty`, () => {
beforeEach(() => {
  myAppLogger = logger({
    prettyPrint: true
  });
});

it(`then pino info method is called on pino instance`, () => {
  const pinoSpy = sinon.spy(pino, 'info');
  myAppLogger.info('info message');
  expect(pinoSpy).to.have.been.called;
  expect(pinoSpy).to.not.throw();
});
});
```

Where `myAppLogger` is just an instance of `pino`

```
pino(options, stream).child(props);
```